How to Fix Old PC with Black Screen, POST Code 00h, and No Beeps After CMOS Battery Replacement and BIOS Flash?
I’m facing a serious issue with my old PC featuring an APC Raptor AT-11/04/03 motherboard and AMIBIOS from American Megatrends (1997). I was getting a "low CMOS battery" error, so I soldered a new lithium battery onto the Benchmarq bq3287AMT RTC module (reference video: YouTube link).
After powering on the PC, I encountered a black screen, continuous single beeps every second, and a POST code of 33h. According to the documentation, this means the BIOS couldn’t find the AMIBOOT.ROM file in the root directory of floppy drive
A. The keyboard also stopped working.
I attempted to flash the BIOS using a floppy disk with the latest version I found online. Unfortunately, things got worse—now there’s no POST, no beeps, just a black screen, and a POST code of 00h, which indicates: "Code copying to specific areas is done. Passing control to INT 19h boot loader next."
I’ve already tried the following steps without success:
Replacing and reseating the 128MB RAM (cleaned with an eraser).
Resetting the CMOS using jumpers.
Using a different monitor.
Removing all external cards and peripherals.
Reflashing the BIOS.

I’d appreciate any advice on how to recover the system or troubleshoot further. Thanks in advance!

If you don't find an answer here, in a few days, try https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com, perhaps. 27 years old might or might qualify for "retro".

You'll need to go through and replace each component, testing as you do. That's an old computer, and the faults may be widespread.
